# Three.js scene dependent on a parameter

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm not fluent in html/javascript and I begin with `three.js`. I did a scene which depends on a parameter that can be controlled by the user.

The code below is a complete minimal example of such a scene. It renders a parametric surface which depends on a parameter `a` that the user can change with an `input type="number"`.

Apparently this is not a good way to proceed: the scene is animated and the animation accelerates when one plays with the parameter, I don't know why. What is a good way to code such a scene?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dupin cyclide</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <label for="a">a: </label>
  <input id="a" type="number" step="0.1" min="0.5" value="0.9"/>
  <script> // change event -----------------------------------------------------
    $("#a").on("change", function(){
      Rendering(this.value);
    })
  </script>

  <script> // cyclide parametrization ------------------------------------------
    function fcyclide(a, c, mu) {
      var b = Math.sqrt(a * a - c * c);
      return function (u, v, vector) {
        var uu = 2 * u * Math.PI; var vv = 2 * v * Math.PI;
        var cosu = Math.cos(uu); var cosv = Math.cos(vv);
        var h = a - c * cosu * cosv;
        var x = (mu * (c - a * cosu * cosv) + b * b * cosu) / h;
        var y = (b * Math.sin(uu) * (a - mu * cosv)) / h;
        var z = b * Math.sin(vv) * (c * cosu - mu) / h;
        vector.x = x; vector.y = y; vector.z = z;
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script> // add cyclide to object --------------------------------------------
    function addCyclide(object, a) {
      var geom = new THREE.ParametricGeometry(
        fcyclide(a, 0.34, 0.56), 40, 40);
      var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
      object.add(mesh);
    }
  </script>

  <script> // three.js --------------------------------------------------------- 
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, aspect, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 4;
    scene.add(camera);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var object = new THREE.Object3D()
    scene.add(object);

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();

    function render() {
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      object.rotation.x += 0.001; object.rotation.y += 0.001;
      requestAnimFrame(render);
    }
  </script>

  <script> // Rendering function -----------------------------------------------
    function Rendering(a) {
      object.children.splice(0); // clear scene
      addCyclide(object, a);
      render();
    }
  </script>

  <script> // Render the scene -------------------------------------------------
    Rendering(0.9);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Apparently this is not a good way to proceed: the scene is animated and the animation accelerates when one plays with the parameter, I don't know why.*

Every time when you call `requestAnimFrame` a timer is started by `setTimeout`. The timer calles `render`, which starts the timer again and repeats the process.
Initiliy the function `render` is called by `Rendering(a)`.
But since `Rendering(a)` is the called by the `change` event too, a new timer started every time when the input is changed. The more often you change the input, the more timer will run simultaneously. This causes the speeding up.

To solve the issue you have to remove the `render` call from `Rendering(a)`.

```
function Rendering(a)
{
    object.children.splice(0);
    addCyclide(object, a);
}
```

But call `requestAnimFrame` once at startup:

```
Rendering(0.9);
requestAnimFrame(render);
```

See the Example, where the suggestion of the answer is applied to the original code of your question:

```js
$("#a").on("change", function(){
    Rendering(this.value);
})

function fcyclide(a, c, mu) {
    var b = Math.sqrt(a * a - c * c);
    return function (u, v, vector) {
        var uu = 2 * u * Math.PI; var vv = 2 * v * Math.PI;
        var cosu = Math.cos(uu); var cosv = Math.cos(vv);
        var h = a - c * cosu * cosv;
        var x = (mu * (c - a * cosu * cosv) + b * b * cosu) / h;
        var y = (b * Math.sin(uu) * (a - mu * cosv)) / h;
        var z = b * Math.sin(vv) * (c * cosu - mu) / h;
        vector.x = x; vector.y = y; vector.z = z;
    }
}

function addCyclide(object, a) {
    var geom = new THREE.ParametricGeometry(fcyclide(a, 0.34, 0.56), 40, 40);
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
    object.add(mesh);
}

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, aspect, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 4;
scene.add(camera);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var object = new THREE.Object3D()
scene.add(object);
window.onresize = resize;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    object.rotation.x += 0.001; object.rotation.y += 0.001;
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function Rendering(a) {
    object.children.splice(0); // clear scene
    addCyclide(object, a);
}

Rendering(0.9);
requestAnimFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="a">a: </label>
<input id="a" type="number" step="0.1" min="0.5" value="0.9"/>
```